# Why is a function returning undefined and how to debug it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm experimenting with closures and classes in data variables and in the example below I'm getting undefined even though I placed a `console.log()` right before the function returns the result and it isn't undefined. It seems to work if it isn't attached to an event handler. Can someone tell me why is this happening and if there is a way to spot where exactly does the error happen? When debugging it goes from the console log straight to the error and I don't see how that makes sense.

To trigger the error run the snippet and click on the names.

The same functions in `$('#Individuals').data('functions')` can be chained and work fine when called in `IndividualsList()`, but not from the event listener, then the result becomes undefined.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var thisWindow = $('#Individuals');
  var randomNames = ['Sonia Small', 'Kurt Archer', 'Reese Mullins', 'Vikram Rayner', 'Jethro Kaye', 'Suhail Randolph', 'Kaydon Crouch', 'Jamaal Elliott', 'Herman Atkins', 'Sia Best', 'Kory Gentry', 'Fallon Sawyer', 'Zayyan Hughes', 'Ayomide Byers', 'Emilia Key', 'Jaxson Guerrero', 'Gracey Frazier', 'Millie Mora', 'Akshay Parker', 'Margareta Emiliana'];
  var generatedIndividuals = [];

  function generateIndividual(name) {
    return {
      IndividualName: name
    };
  }

  function IndividualsList(element) {
    var list = [];

    this.add = function(thisIndividual) {
      $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).add(thisIndividual);
    }
    this.refresh = function() {
      $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).refresh();
    }
    this.sort = function(order) {
      $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).sort(order);
    }
  }

  thisWindow.data('functions', (function() {
    var element = $();
    var list = [];
    return {
      add: function(thisIndividual) {
        list.push(thisIndividual);
        return thisWindow.data('functions');
      },
      init: function(thisElement, thisList) {
        element = thisElement;
        list = thisList;
        return thisWindow.data('functions');
      },
      refresh: function() {
        var thisList = element.html('');
        for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
          thisList.append(
            '<div>' + list[i].IndividualName + '</div>'
          );
        }
        return thisWindow.data('functions');
      },
      sort: function(order) {
        list.sort(function(a, b) {
          if (a.IndividualName < b.IndividualName) return -1 * order;
          if (a.IndividualName > b.IndividualName) return 1 * order;
          return 0;
        });
        console.log(thisWindow.data('functions'));
        return thisWindow.data('functions');
      }
    }
  })());

  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    let nameNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNames.length);
    let thisClient = generateIndividual(randomNames[nameNum]);
    generatedIndividuals.push(thisClient);
  }

  (function() {
    var targetElement = thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list');
    var targetData = {}
    targetElement.data('individualsList', new IndividualsList(targetElement));
    targetData = targetElement.data('individualsList');
    for (let i = 0; i < generatedIndividuals.length; i++) {
      targetData.add(generatedIndividuals[i]);
    }
    targetData.refresh();
  })();

  thisWindow.on('click', '.individuals-list', function() {
    var thisElem = $(this);
    var order = parseInt(thisElem.data('order'));
    thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list').data('individualsList').sort(order).refresh();
    thisElem.data('order', order * (-1));
  });

});
```

```css
.individuals-list {
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Individuals">
  <div class="individuals-list" data-order="1"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kethus/ymgwrLhj/

Comment: which one? I see all the methods in `IndividualsList` have no return statement ... any others?

Comment: Which method is returning undefined?

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added clarifications in the question.

Comment: @EKW The sort inside `$('#Individuals').data('functions')`, called from within `IndividualsList()` from the event listener at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value doesn't transfer from the closure to the instance that called it, the class has to be changed like so:

```
function IndividualsList(element) {
  var list = [];

  this.add = function(thisIndividual) {
    return $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).add(thisIndividual);
  }
  this.refresh = function() {
    return $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).refresh();
  }
  this.sort = function(order) {
    return $('#Individuals').data('functions').init(element, list).sort(order);
  }
}
```

The breakpoint could have been in one of `IndividualsList()`'s methods so it can be noticed that the closure returns the desired object while the method does not. Different names for either the functions or methods would help to reinforce that they are separate.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the wrong `sort()` function, hence call it incorrectly so it returns undefined. Then you call refresh() on undefined that was returned from sort. Here's why:

In your IFFE, you use .data() to set the `data = new IndvidualsList` on `thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list')`

**This code:**

```
thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list').data('individualsList')
```

**Returns that instantiated IndividualsList Object:**

```
IndividualsList = $1
add: function(thisIndividual)
refresh: function()
sort: function(fieldName, order)
  IndividualsList Prototype
```

Note the `sort()` function's definition. Sort in this object requires two parameters, `fieldName` and `order`; yet you call `sort()` and only pass `order`;

This indicates your expectation for the sort() function is incorrect or the wrong sort function is being made available at that line of code (in the click handler).

**How to debug**

1. Set a breakpoint at line 132 of the provided JavaScript in the
   Fiddle.
2. Click a name in the list.
3. While at the breakpoint (execution paused), move to the console and run this in the console:
       `thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list').data('individualsList')`
4. Note the sort() function definition in the list of functions
5. Next, in the console run this statement:

   thisWindow.find('div.individuals-list').data('individualsList').sort(order)
6. Note the return is `undefined` **<-- This is the issue**

Comment: The `fieldName` parameter is left over from me shortening the code to only what's needed for the recreational example, I missed that part. It is not related to the problem. There are supposed to be many `.individual-list`s, each with its own instance of `IndividualsList()` and to avoid declaring the functions every time I attached them to `#Individuals` instead. Each function in `$('#Individuals').data('functions')` is supposed to return `data('functions')` so they can be chained without searching the element again.

Comment: I didn't mean that I don't know how to debug in general, it's that even if I place a breakpoint right at the location of the `console.log` and check the value of `thisWindow.data('functions')` it would not be undefined. Then immediately after that it says it's undefined.

Comment: I don't understand how it can be so easy to dismiss what I've stated above when I provided the output that came directly from **your own code**. Stating that the fieldName parameter "is not related to the problem" is just silly. I showed you that you are calling the wrong sort function and showed you where - yet some how I am incorrect. So either provide the correct code that you want someone else to troubleshoot for you or open your mind to someone else's help. The `undefined` is caused by the .sort() function returning undefined. Please check that out for yourself.

Comment: I've modified the "How to debug" for your consideration.

Comment: Your debug part made me see my mistake, and thank you, but your answer wasn't the solution. I wasn't calling the wrong function, I just somehow assumed that the return from `#Individuals` would transfer to `.individuals-list` and continue the chain. To fix it I just had to insert `return ` in front of the actions of each method in `IndividualsList()`.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could be so wrong so you could be so right. My only goal was to assist you finding a solution you sought help with. In my inept attempt to help you were able to discover a solution I didn't help you find. Awesome. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165851/discussion-between-nadroev-and-randy-casburn).

Comment: And what was the result of doing: _To fix it I just had to insert return in front of the actions of each method in IndividualsList()_ ? The result I am referring to arrives at step 4 from my debugging steps above. OH! The correct version of the `sort()` function shows up.  Interesting.